# C - User input capped to 8 characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, user-input

I'm trying to write a function that can be called for user input, therefore I can just call it whenever and it can be assigned to a variable.
However, for some reason it seems to be capping the input at 8 characters, regardless of if it is above or below 8 characters.

```
char * userInput(){
    char * user_input;
    user_input = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    printf("Type > ");
    scanf("%s",user_input);
    printf("%ld",sizeof(user_input));
    return user_input;
}
```

output

Type > TheIsTheSentence

8Hello TheIsThe

Comment: `sizeof(user_input)` returns the size of the _pointer_ `user_input`, which on a 64 bit architecture is 8 bytes. You probably want `strlen(user_input)` instead to get the length of the string _contained_ in `user_input` (i.e. what `user_input` points to)

Comment: you would need to share your output code as well. The input looks ok besides the already mentioned sizeof(user_input)

Comment: @Ber Isn't the output code included there? (printf)

Comment: was talking about the part "Hello TheIsThe".
Also you might want to make it explicit how many characters you want to read as you allocated memory for 100.
So scanf("%99s",user_input);

Comment: Notice that there is absolutely no benefit in writing `char * user_input;
    user_input = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);` instead of `char * user_input = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic statement is this

```
printf("%ld",sizeof(user_input)); /* It desn't return the number of char stored in user_input  */
```

as `user_input` is a character pointer and s*izeof pointer is always `4` byte on `32` bit machine and `8` bytes on 64 bit machine*.

My suggestion is to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`. For e.g

Declare a character pointer and allocate memory.

```
char * user_input = NULL;
user_input = malloc(sizeof(*user_input) * MAX_BUF_SIZE); /* Instead of magic number use macro */
```

Do proper error handling of `malloc()`. For e.g

```
if(user_input == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Scan the input using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`. for e.g

```
size_t retStrCspn = 0;
if(fgets(user_input, MAX_BUF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
   /* fgets success. next task is remove the trailing \n char read by fgets() */
   user_input[retStrCspn = strcspn(user_input, "\n")] = 0; /* remove the trailing & use the return value */
}
```

Now print the length, don't use `sizeof`, use the return value of `strcspn()` for example

```
printf("%zu", retStrCspn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
printf("%ld",sizeof(user_input));
```

Write:

```
printf("%ld",strlen(user_input));
```

Note that your program will behave badly if you write more than 99 characters in the input.

Comment: Even better (if your compiler supports it) is `%zu`.  `sizeof` and `strlen` return type `size_t`, which is compatible with type `unsigned` on some machines, `unsigned long` on others.  But `%zu` takes care of this.